# How Can I read the Aruco Markers in a a bitmap image in C#?

Tags: c#, aruco

I have a bitmap image of multiple aruco markers.  I need to just output the number of markers that can be read from the image.

I have looked all over, but am not able to find a good way to do this in C#.  I know this can be done in C++, but can it be done in C#?

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to do this?  Is this a supported function in visual studio?

I attached an example of an image I want to be able to read the aruco markers from.  I know I will not be able to read all of them, but I want to be able to read as many as possible.

[image: Image Example]

Comment: No, Visual Studio is an IDE, it will not help you to do these kind of things.
But... you don't find anything when searching "aruco marker c#" in Google?

Comment: No, I tried to find Aruko markers in C#, but nothing that was supported.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried paying attention to https://bitbucket.org/horizongir/aruco.net project? It looks like exactly what you are looking for.